# Image view image need to change periodically in android

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have an image view. So in the image view i want to change the images after a certain time period. Images are coming from an array list. Now when the no of images are 3 or more than 3, it is working perfect. But when it is 2, my logic is not working. Second image is visible for a moment and then again changed to first image here is my code:

```
r = new Runnable(){
        int i = 0;
        public void run(){
            iv.setImageBitmap(alBmps.get(i));
                i++;                
                if(i >= alBmps.size()){
                     i = 0;
                 }

             iv.postDelayed(r, 5000); //set to go off again in 5 seconds.
         }
    };
    iv.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Can any one help me what changes i need on the above code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

declare variables

```
static int i=0; 
private Timer myTimer;
```

in your onCreate or on button click where you want to call and start the methods

```
myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{           
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {   
        TimerMethod();
    }
}, 500, 5000);
```

add these methods to your class

```
private void TimerMethod()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run()
    {
       if(i<alBmps.size())
       {
           iv.setImageBitmap(alBmps.get(i));
       }
       else
       {
           i=0;
           iv.setImageBitmap(alBmps.get(i));
       }   
       i++;
     }
};
```

Comment: Sorry. This is also not working. Same issue is coming.

Comment: your second image will be visible for five seconds, what is the exact problem your are facing

Comment: second image is not visible for 5 seconds. It is coming for just a moment and again the first image is showing. It is coming just like a flash

Comment: please paste your complete activity

Comment: Basically the images are downloaded from server and then i am showing. Let me try with two static image from drawable.

Comment: then try with my code in separate class it should work , there should be some problem with variable declaration or initialization , in your code you have used post delayed two times..one for 1 sec and another one for 5 sec.. why so?

Comment: if you are downloading images from server then atleast try with 15-20 sec interval so image get proper time to get downloaded

Comment: 1 sec is for the delay for the first time. Same as you used for 500 ms. Other is for interval.

Comment: ohk.. please try with my code and declare your variable static and increase interval to 15-20 secs

Comment: I have changed it with static images. but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46573/discussion-between-arindam-mukherjee-and-vaibhav-agarwal)